# how to randomly select a certain number of elements from a list

Tags: scala

I would like to randomly select a certain number of elements from a list and make another list out of it. For example out of a list containing 100 elements I would like to randomly select 20 of the elements and store it in another list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `util.Random` to shuffle the list and then take the first 20 elements :

```
scala> import scala.util.Random
import scala.util.Random

scala> val l = List.range(1,100)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, ...., 98, 99)

scala> Random.shuffle(l).take(20)
res2: List[Int] = List(11, 32, 95, 56, 90, ..., 45, 20)
```

Comment: I downvote code-only answers (which this was at first) reflexively. It's not a race, and I don't see any point in rushing to post some code and then edit your answer once you've staked your claim.

Comment: Fair enough, and I do agree with you on the race part (although I would argue that, in some cases, this question being one of them, code-only answers are perfectly fine).

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do this is a one-liner:

```
scala> util.Random.shuffle((1 to 100).toList).take(10)
res0: List[Int] = List(63, 21, 49, 70, 73, 14, 23, 88, 28, 97)
```

You could try to get clever and avoid shuffling the entire list, but it's almost definitely not necessary, and it'll be very easy to get it wrong.